# R: Reformatting data file

Tags: r, reformatting

I have what I suspect is a simple data reformatting question.  The data file (txt) is structured with the observation numbers on separate lines,

```
1
45 65
78 56
2
89 34
39 55
```

The desired output is,

```
1 45 65
1 78 56
2 89 34
2 39 55
```

Suggestions on how to make that conversion would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could read the file with `readLines`.  Create an index variable and split the 'lines'.  Remove the first element of the list elements, use `read.table` to read the file, and `unnest`

```
 lines <- readLines('file.txt')
 library(stringr)
 #remove leading/lagging spaces if any 
 lines <- str_trim(lines) 
 #create the index mentioned above based on white space 
 indx  <- !grepl('\\s+', lines)
 #cumsum the above index to create grouping
 indx1 <- cumsum(indx)
 #split the lines with and change the names of the list elements 
 lst <- setNames(split(lines, indx1), lines[indx])
 #Use unnest after reading with read.table 
 library(tidyr)
 unnest(lapply(lst, function(x) read.table(text=x[-1])), gr)
 #   gr V1 V2
 #1  1 45 65
 #2  1 78 56
 #3  2 89 34
 #4  2 39 55
```

Or we can use `Map` from `base R` approach

```
 do.call(rbind,Map(cbind, gr=names(lst), 
             lapply(lst, function(x) read.table(text=x[-1]))))
```

Comment: Thanks you.  Works as expected.

Comment: @ksing Okay, thanks for updating that.  So, I guess the error is fixed?

Comment: The answer provided above works with tidyr 0.2.0 but seems to break under 0.3.0 failing with **object 'gr' not found**.   Is there perhaps a quick fix?  Thanks.

Comment: @ksing Thanks for the feedback. I was able to reproduce the problem in 0.3.0.  It may be a bug.  We can do this using `base R`. i.e. `do.call(rbind,Map(cbind, gr=names(lst), lapply(lst, function(x) read.table(text=x[-1]))))`

Comment: Thank you. After a bit of searching I updated with `lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) read.table(text=x[-1]))` and `out <- Reduce(rbind, Map(cbind, lst2, gr = names(lst2)))` earlier today but will use the above.  Incidentally, this solution sorts numerically (i.e., 1-2-3-4...N) on gr whereas the tidyr solution would lsort as a string(?).

Comment: @ksing I think in both cases, the `gr` will be `character` column.  You can check the class using `str(out)`.  Also, if it is a `factor`, then convert to `numeric` by as.numeric(as.character(..`